# Websocket implementation not working in Apache Ofbiz

Tags: websocket, tomcat8, ofbiz

I am checking the Websocket implementation in Apache Ofbiz.
I followed the parent ticket [OFBIZ-7073](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OFBIZ-7073) and its child tickets.
But I am getting the following error-

> ExamplePushNotifications.js:23 WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:8443/example/ws/pushNotifications' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

I think that the request is redirecting to control servlet rather than tomcat server. Therefore IMO, we need to make some changes in example/web.xml.

How should I proceed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Pallavi, I think this most fits in OFBiz the dev ML ;)

Comment: Hi Jacques, I have posted the question on User ML, I will also post the question on Dev ML. Thanks!

Comment: The functionality is fixed and web sockets are now working on the latest code base.